# Can't figure out how to perform arithmetic in a bash loop (for)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, math, scripting

```
#! /bin/bash
sum=0
for number in $*
do
    x=$(( sum + number ))
    echo $x
done
```

I'm simply trying to create a script called "add" which will add positional parameters when executed. Instead of adding the numbers, it simply displays them as a loop would normally. E.g.

```
$ add 1 2 3 4 5 6
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, `for number in $*` is generally a code smell -- it gets you into trouble with entries with whitespace, with entries that can be interpreted as globs, and in other cases. Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, use `for number; do` or `for number in "$@"; do` (both of these are entirely equivalent). See also http://shellcheck.net/, which will detect this for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never update `sum`. Did you mean this?

```
sum=0
for number in "$@"; do
  sum=$((sum + number))
  echo "$sum"
done
```

(The `echo $sum` goes outside the loop if you only want a final sum, rather than a running total, written to standard output.)

Comment: That worked perfectly, I had tried updating sum before but I think I was using $ within the arithmetic brackets. Thank you very much.

Comment: The only difference between `sum` and `$sum` inside `$((...))` is the former defaults to 0 if it is undefined, while the latter results in a syntax error.

Comment: +1.  Also, I'm curious: under what conditions does `$sum` result in a syntax error inside `$((...))`?  I tested `unset x; echo $(($x+1))` and it just returns `1`.

Comment: I should say, it *could* produce a syntax error. `+` is a valid unary operator, so `$(( + 1 ))` is valid. Try `unset x; product=$(( $x * 1 ))`.

Comment: Interesting!  So, `$x` seems to obey normal shell rules were an empty `$x` disappears from the command.  I note that shellcheck wants all `$` removed from arithmetic but there are times when I would rather have a missing value cause an error.